# Given a $n-2$ dimensional closed submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is it the boundary of some $n-1$ dimensional submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, geometric-topology

Let $\Sigma$ an oriented $n-2$ dimensional closed submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it always the boundary of some oriented $n-1$ dimensional submanifold?

Comment: Can you make the boundary of a mobius strip into the boundary of an oriented surface, like a disc, without self-intersections?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, but does this work always?